# Database to datagridview - between dates not working when dates are in label

Tags: vb.net, date, datagridview, between

I think I've tried almost every combination and can not get this to work. 
This line works without a problem :

```
Dim SQLString As String = "SELECT * FROM PROMGL WHERE DATPRO Between #1/1/2014# and #3/3/2014#"
```

But when I out those exact dates in label6 and lebel 7 I get no results in datagridview

```
Dim SQLString As String = "SELECT * FROM PROMGL WHERE DATPRO between " & Label6.Text & " and " & Label7.Text
```

*One of the combinations I've tried*

Comment: Are you using MS Access? Also why not use a datepicker instead of labels?

Comment: No, DBF database. Regarding datepicker, I don't want to change users habits, also I am using combobox for every month.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing pound # signs to enclose the dates:

```
Dim SQLString As String = "SELECT * FROM PROMGL WHERE DATPRO between #" & Label6.Text & "# and #" & Label7.Text & "#"
```

A better way is to [use parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparameter.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-2), to avoid SQL injection.